# Ruby recursion through array not getting to last value

Tags: ruby, arrays, recursion, lambda, functional-programming

I'm trying to recursively progress through an array. From what I'm seeing from debugging it, it's returning from the last level of recursion and stopping execution instead of returning to the previous level of recursion.

With a sample input:

```
["(", #<Alpha:0x007f80fc9e0de8 @value="abc">, 
  "(", #<Alpha:0x007f80fc9e0cf8 @value="def">, 
  #<Number:0x007f80fc9e0c30 @value=2>, 
  #<Number:0x007f80fc9e0b68 @value=3>, ")", ")"]
```

It returns:

```
[[#<Alpha:0x007f80fb63dac0 @value="def">, 
  #<Number:0x007f80fb63d9f8 @value=2>, #<Number:0x007f80fb63d930 @value=3>]]
```

It should return:

```
[[[#<Alpha:0x007f80fb7a4058 @value="def">,
 #<Number:0x007f80fb787f48 @value=2>,
 #<Number:0x007f80fb787e80 @value=3>], #<Alpha:0x007f80fc9e0de8 @value="abc">]]
```

Here is the code:

```
def set_execution_order
  ordered = []

  _set_execution_order = lambda do |tokens, ret = nil|
    token = tokens.delete_at 0

    case token
    when "("
      return _set_execution_order[tokens, []]
    when ")"
      ordered << ret
      return ret
    else
      ret << token
      return _set_execution_order[tokens, ret]
    end
  end

  _set_execution_order[@value]
  ordered
end
```

Comment: How are `tokens` and `@value` defined?

Comment: @August `tokens` and `@value` are an array of `"("`, `")"` and objects representing alphanumeric characters (`Alpha`) and numbers (`Number`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the second-last ")" that return immediately before it reach the last ")". Note that return in lambda will also return from the parent function. This code should work:

UPDATE: I think an array is not sufficient to get the data since it lacks the link between its member to the parent container. A tree data structure is required to store the information and a child can link with parent through function parent here. I rewrite the code, and this returns result as expected:

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :parent, :children, :values
  def initialize    
    @children = []
    @parent = nil
    @values = []
  end

  def add_child(child)
    child.parent = self
    @children << child
  end  

  def add_value(value)
    @values << value
  end

  def to_a
    result = values.clone
    @children.each do |child|
      result << child.to_a
    end
    result
  end
end

def set_execution_order(value)    
  _set_execution_order = lambda do |tokens, node|    
    token = tokens.shift
    case token
    when nil
      return node
    when "("
      child = Node.new
      node.add_child(child)
      _set_execution_order[tokens, child]            
    when ")"      
      _set_execution_order[tokens, node.parent]            
    else
      node.add_value(token)
      return _set_execution_order[tokens, node]
    end
  end

  root = Node.new
  _set_execution_order[value, root]
  root
end

set_execution_order(["(", 1, "(", 2, 3, ")", 4, "(", 5, 6, ")", ")"]).to_a #returns  => [[1, 4, [2, 3], [5, 6]]]
```

Comment: That code didn't work, so I replaced `new_ret` with the `ordered` array that the lambda is closed over. I ended up with something better I think: `[[#<Alpha:0x007f8832c19410 @value="def">, #<Number:0x007f8832c18ee8 @value=2>, #<Number:0x007f8832c13268 @value=3>], [...]]` I just don't remember where I've seen `[...]` before or what it means.

Comment: [...] means an array that has a member that points to itself, which could happen when you do something recursively. Try a = [], a[0] = a, puts a. The problem is more complicated than I thought. Recursing by checking the first character is not trivial and has several edge cases to think about. Will think about this when I have more time.

Comment: I've updated the answer above (I don't know why my previous comments is being deleted)

Comment: Thank you for your time. I managed to find the solution right now after I sat down and drew out the problem with a pen and paper, step by step. I'm posting it as the answer right now. I hadn't had a chance to look yesterday at what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

What led me to the answer was simply taking the time to sit down and draw out the recursion step by step.

After drawing out the steps, I saw that the results of the recursion needed to be appended to the return value. Here's the code:

```
def set_execution_order
  _set_execution_order = lambda do |tokens, ret = []|
    token = tokens.delete_at 0

    case token
    when "("
      # append the new array to what we're returning
      ret << _set_execution_order[tokens, []] 
    when ")"
      # we're at the end of what we need
      ret
    else
      # no new array to append, keep going
      ret << token
      return _set_execution_order[tokens, ret]
    end
  end

  _set_execution_order[@value]
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the correct answer though. If @value = ["(", "(", 2, 3, ")", 1, ")"], the function will return [[[2, 3]]] because of the second-to-last ")". Is that your desired output?

Comment: Yeah I realized that this morning. I'm gonna end up using a tree.